How do you flatten a slice of arrays without extra allocation?
In Go, if I have a slice of arrays of a given type, how can I convert that to just a slice of that same type?
Specifically, is it possible to do this without allocating memory for a new backing array?  (Meaning, I'm ignoring the obvious option of looping through the original slice and copying its values into a new slice.)
For example, what I want is:
func convert(sliceOfArrays [][4]byte) []byte {
    // solution goes here
}

The exact types and array lengths are unimportant.
I asked and answered my own question since I couldn't find anything like this on SO and wanted it recorded.

Note, this is about "converting" not "flattening". Flattening affects dimensionality without changing element types.  The question is about one-dimensional slices and the answer allows for conversion of types.  The question was changed by someone else.

What you call "conversion" is irrelevant here. As your function signature shows, you have a two-dimensional container (slice of arrays) and want to output a one-dimensional container (a single slice). That's effectively "flattening" and has nothing to do with conversion

(Note, this answer and its code comments assume an understanding of how slices in Go are represented in memory, specifically "backing arrays".  If unfamiliar, read here: https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro)
Yes, this is possible without allocating memory for a new backing array.  Using the unsafe package, this is fairly straightforward.  Here is a heavily-commented example:
import "unsafe"

func convert(sliceOfArrays [][4]byte) []byte {
    // create an *unsafe.ArbitraryType, specifically *[4]byte, from the original slice's backing array
    sliceData := unsafe.SliceData(sliceOfArrays)

    // convert to an unsafe.Pointer; this is necessary to allow the next step to be possible
    pointer := unsafe.Pointer(sliceData)

    // convert to a *byte
    // NOTE this is a pointer to a single byte, not a slice of bytes
    // from the documentation: "unsafe.Pointer can be converted to a pointer value of any type"
    bytePointer := (*byte)(pointer)

    // calculate how many total elements (bytes, in this case) will be in the resulting slice
    // in this case, this is just 4 * len(sliceOfArrays) / 1
    length := int(unsafe.Sizeof([4]byte{})) * len(sliceOfArrays) / int(unsafe.Sizeof(byte(0)))
    // more generally, this formula is:
    // numberOfResultingElements = sizeOfOriginalElement * numberOfOriginalElements / sizeOfResultingElement

    // unsafe.Slice creates a new slice of bytes
    // the backing array of this slice starts at the memory location of `bytePointer`
    // the slice has both length and capacity of `length`
    return unsafe.Slice(bytePointer, length)
}

Note, the original slice sliceOfArrays and the return value of convert() are sharing the same backing array, so modification to one will affect the other:
mySliceOfArrays := [][4]byte{{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}}
sliceOfBytes := convert(mySliceOfArrays)

fmt.Println(mySliceOfArrays) // [[0 1 2 3] [4 5 6 7]]
fmt.Println(sliceOfBytes)    // [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]

// changing the original changes the result
mySliceOfArrays[0][2] = 99
fmt.Println(sliceOfBytes)    // [0 1 99 3 4 5 6 7]

// changing the result changes the original
sliceOfBytes[7] = 13
fmt.Println(mySliceOfArrays) // [[0 1 99 3] [4 5 6 13]]

All this code in the Go Playground
(Note, new allocations such as from sliceOfBytes = append(sliceOfBytes, value) will likely result in a new backing array being transparently allocated for sliceOfBytes and its "connection" to mySliceOfArrays being broken.)
This works, in part, because:

an array of elements in Go is represented by a contiguous block of memory, with no header information
the backing array of a slice of arrays has an equivalent memory layout to that of a slice of non-arrays of the same element type
unsafe.Slice can create a new slice out of an arbitrary block of memory

unsafe.Slice doesn't really care about what the original data was meant to represent.  You could change convert() to return []float64 if you wanted to get weird, as long as you re-calculate the slice length appropriately.  In the above example, you'd need two [4]byte for each float64 in the result.  Here is convertToFloat64s() in the Go Playground
(If anyone knows of non-obvious issues with this method, please leave a comment.)
